# Prove $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/H\times G/K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assuming $H,K$ are normal subgroups of G and $H\cap K=\{e\}$.

I'm really struggling with this one. I am supposed to use this to show that $Z_{mn}\cong Z_n\times Z_{m}$ iff $n$ and $m$ are coprime, which I can do fine. I'm just stuck on proving this fact.

Comment: Can you prove that the natural map from $G$ to $G/H\times G/K$ is injective?

Comment: I guess my problem is that I don't have the first guess at what mapping to use.

Comment: What is the most obvious map from $G$ to $G/H$?

Comment: Oh gosh I'm an idiot. Okay I see, I'll try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\phi(g) = (gH,gK)$, what can we say about $g$ if $(gH,gK) = (H,K) = e_{G/H \times G/K}$?