# Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ such that $H \cap K=\{e\}$. Show that $G$ is isomorphic with some subgroup of $G/H \times G/K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group, direct-product

> Let $G$ be a group with identity $e$. Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ such that $H \cap K=\{e\}$. Show that $G$ is isomorphic with some subgroup of $G/H \times G/K$.

It seems that from $H \cap K=\{e\}$ I have that $hk=kh$ for all $h\in H, k\in K$. I don’t know if I can apply any of the isomorphism theorems here since I don’t know if $H \subset K$ or if $K \subset H$. Hints on what can we do here?

Comment: Try constructing an injective map from $G$ to $G/H\times G/K$.

Comment: Something like $g \mapsto (g + H, g + K)$? Is this even well defined? The elements of the direct product of the quotient groups are sets so this would be an tuple of sets…?

Comment: You mean $g \to (gH,gK)$, and yes, it is well-defined. If you have homomorphisms $G \to A$ and $G \to B$, then you can use them to define a homomorphism $G \to A \times B$.

Comment: @DerekHolt What’s the difference between $(g+H, g+K)$ and $(gH, gK)$? Doesn’t this depend on the operation we’re considering?

Comment: @JimingLe You need to worry about well-definedness when the element that you are mapping has multiples ways to represent it. For example, mapping $G/H\to G/K$ by $gH\mapsto gK$. This may not be well-defined, since there are multiple ways to represent an element in $gH$, and they may get mapped to different elements in $G/K$.

Comment: Please search the site for identical questions before posting. This is a standard problem,, and it has been addressed before.

Answer (score 2):

Since $H,K\lhd G$, so $\forall g\in G, gH=Hg, gK=Kg$.

Let the map $\varphi:G\to\frac GH\times\frac GK$ as $\varphi(g)=(gH,gK)$.

**Part 1: Show this map is injection**

If $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)$, then $xH=yH, xK=yK$. This is equivalent to $y^{-1}xH=H, y^{-1}xK=K$.

This means $y^{-1}x\in H,K$, so $y^{-1}x\in H\cap K$,so $y^{-1}x$ must be $e$, so $x=y$.

So, $\varphi$ is injection.

**Part 2: Show this map is homomorphism**

Then, let's calculate $\varphi(x)\varphi(y)$.
$$\varphi(x)\varphi(y)=(xH,xK)\cdot(yH,yK)=(xHyH,xKyK)=(xyHH,xyKK)=(xyH,xyK)=\varphi(xy)$$

So, $\varphi$ is group homomorphism.

**Last part: Prove the question**

Then, $\varphi:G\to\varphi G$ is isomorphism($\varphi$ in this case is bijective homomorphism.), and $\varphi G$ is subgroup of $\frac GH\times\frac GK$.

Comment: Please move your answer to the previous identical question.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You mean this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213807/prove-g-is-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of-g-h-times-g-k

Comment: That's the one I found; I'm sure there are others... but that one does not have a full answer, so yours might be welcome there.